# MVC 4 Simplemembership own contextclass

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm trying to implement the simplemembership with my own context class like so:

```
public class DbInitializer : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

This work fine and I get all the tables I need: Cars , UserProfiles, Webpages.Memberships, Webpages.Roles, WebPages.UserInRoles. But when I move all the model classes to another project and run it I only get Car and UserProfile so I'm wondering what more I have to do to get the rest of the tables?

Comment: Is there a difference between your `seed methods` in the projects?

Comment: I haven't defined any seed methods. All I did was move the AccountModels to another project and also created my own contextclass with public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; } inside.

Comment: did you enable migration? Updated database from PMC etc?

Comment: Yes. It's something about moving it to another project that it doesn't like. When I do it I only get the UserProfile table and no Webpages tables.

Comment: What are your configuration classes like in both the projects? Code?

Comment: I haven't done anything to my Web.config file and the other project is a classlibrary where I have my models and contextclass.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) is your solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [SimpleSecurity open source project](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/) for an example of how to put SimpleMembership in its own context.  Additional entities are also added to the project to enhance the security model.  This is developed as a class library that can be incorporated into any MVC application.

You did not provide enough information to figure out what went wrong when you moved it to a new project. My guess is that you did not call [WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.initializedatabaseconnection%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). Take a look at this [article on customizing SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html) which shows the best way to initialize the database.